# Problem with Rich faces panelBar?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am using rich faces panel bar control in my application. There some problem with the control.

The code is some thing like this

```
<rich:panelBar contentClass="some-class">
    <rich:panelBarItem label="Panel 1" headerClass="some-css-class">
        Contents 1
    </rich:panelBarItem>
    <rich:panelBarItem label="Panel 2" headerClass="some-css-class">
        Contents 2
    </rich:panelBarItem>
    <rich:panelBarItem label="Panel 3" headerClass="some-css-class">
        Contents 3
    </rich:panelBarItem>
</rich:panelBar>
```

Now I wan't to show header background color of active panel item green and all other should be blue. I tried it using 'headerClassActive' property of the panel bar but is not working.

Is there any thing missing.

Comment: headerClassActive should work. Check with the WebDeveloper plugin whether the appropriate class has been assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many try I got the solution. I don't know why this is done using "**headerStyleActive**" but it is working.

```
 <rich:panelBar contentClass="some-class">
    <rich:panelBarItem label="Panel 1" headerClass="some-css-class" headerStyleActive="background-color:green;">
        Contents 1
    </rich:panelBarItem>
    <rich:panelBarItem label="Panel 2" headerClass="some-css-class" headerStyleActive="background-color:green;">
        Contents 2
    </rich:panelBarItem>
    <rich:panelBarItem label="Panel 3" headerClass="some-css-class" headerStyleActive="background-color:green;">
        Contents 3
    </rich:panelBarItem>
</rich:panelBar>
```

All I did is used **headerStyleActive** property of **rich:panelBarItem** and not **headerClassActive**. This is working code .

I got this solution from  [this](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/richfaces-issues/2008-December/027385.html)  page.

Answer (score 1):

In your css file define the .rich-panelbar-header-act class and override with your specifics.

e.g
    .rich-panelbar-header-act{
        background-color: blue;
    }